# PHP handle Upload Functions

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form I'm building that uploads the form content into a database (MySQL) and a separate page to display the contents of the database. So far everything works great. I just needed the users to be able to upload an image file along with the form and I need the image itself and a few more fields that I may add to display on the page with the database contents. I have created the fields and the image uploader but when I run my program, it does not display the added fields and photo. I have since created new columns for the new fields in my database already.

How do I accomplish this by modifying the existing code?

I wrote these codes to pull the data from the database.

```
<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from students where student_id = '$get_id'")or die(mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $cl = $row['class'];
?>
<div class="alert alert-success">STUDENT DETAILS</div>
    <div class="span6">
        Image: <strong><?php echo $row['image']; ?></strong><hr>
        Name: <strong><?php echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['middlename']." ".$row['lastname']; ?></strong><hr>
        Gender: <strong><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></strong><hr>
        Date Of Birth: <strong><?php echo $row['dob']; ?></strong><hr>
        Address: <strong><?php echo $row['address']; ?></strong><hr>
        Payment Status: <strong><?php echo $row['status']; ?></strong><hr>
        Prefix: <strong><?php echo $row['prefix']; ?></strong><hr>
        suffix: <strong><?php echo $row['suffix']; ?></strong><hr>
        Email Address: <strong><?php echo $row['eaddress']; ?></strong><hr>
        Phone Number: <strong><?php echo $row['pnumber']; ?></strong><hr>
        School Year: <strong><?php echo $row['syear']; ?></strong><hr>
        Subjects Enrolled: <strong><?php echo $row['senrolled']; ?></strong><hr>
        Number of Units: <strong><?php echo $row['Nofunits']; ?></strong><hr>
    </div>
    <div class="span5">
        Class: <strong><?php echo $row['class']; ?></strong><hr>
        <?php 
            $query2 = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from class where class_name = '$cl'")or die(mysqli_error());
            while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
                $category = $row1['category'];
                $fee = $row1['fee'];
        }?>
        Class Category: <strong><?php echo $category; ?></strong><hr>
        Class Fee: <strong><?php echo $fee; ?></strong><hr>
        Transport: <strong><?php echo $row['transport']; ?></strong><hr>
        Route: <strong><?php echo $row['route']; ?></strong><hr>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ Bobby Tables is going to have some fun with your database, especially if $cl is unvalidated user input.  Please do some research into prepared statements.

Comment: If you have the required knowledge to put me through, I'll appreciate it. I'm just a student trying to learn.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, Please Gwaza, Can I see the code that you use to upload the files to database

Comment: Do you mean the codes that are supposed to pull the data to the view page? That's the problem I am having. My system is communicating with the database quite okay but data is not being pulled to the view page. I can just send you the codes for my form and the view.php.